# Принять меры чего, по чему, к чему?

Tags: предлоги, управление

В справочнике по "Пунктуации и управлению в русском языке" Д. Э. Розенталя указано:

> Меры (совокупность действий для осуществления чего-л.) **чего** и **по чему**. Меры наказания. Меры по улучшению ухода за посевами. Принять меры **к чему** и против чего. Принять меры к ликвидации прорыва. Принять меры против распространения гриппа.

Каким образом надо выбирать между этими тремя вариантами (с "против чего" всё понятно)? В чём разница? Почему "меры **к** ликвидации", а не "меры **по** ликвидации" или "меры ликвидации"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все сочетания корректны, но различаются по употреблению.

1. **Меры по ликвидации** - меры, связанные с ликвидацией, направленные на ликвидацию. Предлог используется для обозначения характера мер - *какие это меры*.

> Весь месяц отдел занимался разработкой мер по ликвидации беспорядка на
>   складах.

2. **(Принять) меры к ликвидации** - совершить действия, направленные на ликвидацию. Предлог привязан не к слову "меры", а используется для обозначения направленности действия словосочетания "принять меры" - *в каком направлении принять меры*, ради какого результата.

> Были приняты меры к ликвидации выявленных нарушений.

3. **Меры ликвидации** - меры, *заключающиеся в ликвидации* (содержание меры: ликвидировать что-то, кого-то).

> Террориста удалось остановить только применением к нему мер(ы)
>   ликвидации.